# the $watch handler does not have access to the controller's this

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to update a controller variable value whenever a value in a service changes.

```
vm.changeMe;
$scope.$watch(function() { return service.value }, function(new, old) {
    // does not have access to vm.changeMe
})
```

I've pasted a more complete example, but my general question is; how do I set a controller variable from within the $watch callback?

https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/32498e02df732445bdfe

I'm using Angular 1.4 and I'm using the controllerAs syntax.

Comment: `vm.changeMe` should be accessible in your `$watch`. Is your `$watch` called? Have you tried `console.log(vm.notes)`?

Comment: no reason you shouldn't have access ... provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: As long as it's attached to the scope, you should be able to access `vm.changeMe` inside your `$scope.$watch` function

Comment: I can't figure out how to get a simple angular app working in fiddle so I can't provide a demo.  I've modified the gist in my original question to have the complete code example.

Comment: The problem has something to do with how "this" works in javascript.  In all of my controllers, I set a variable named "vm" to this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$watch` for this at all. You just have to bind your controller variable to the service variable. In your controller, do:

```
vm.changeMe = service.value;
```

---

Due to charlietfl's comment, I'll edit to say that you can reference the service itself in the scope, though I'm not sure if it's recommended:

```
vm.service = service;
```

Then you'll have the changes in the scope along with the changes in the service.

Comment: won't work if it's a primitive...important to note that

Comment: True. I've done this but I'm not sure if I would recommend, that is referencing the service itself in the controller: vm.service = service;

Comment: that or recommend that `value` is object in service

Comment: I do have that working, but it breaks when I use a custom filter.  vm.changeMe = filter(service.valueCollection)

Answer (score 0):

In my app, there are multiple controllers.  In each controller I assign "this" to "vm.

```
var vm = this;
```

I had a few controllers in which I forgot to declare the "vm" with "var"

```
// bad
vm = this;

// good
var vm = this;
```

As a result, "vm" inside the $scope.$watch callback was referencing another controller.